# Spell check setting not found in Windows 10 settings app

Tags: windows-10, spell-check

I need to turn on the spell check in Win10 (I haven't preinstalled MS Word or any spell check programmes). So I searched web, and was told to go to `Settings -> Devices -> Typing` and then turn on the spell check, which was expected to look like this (image from [website](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25843-spell-checking-turn-off-windows-10-a.html))

[image]

However, when I opened the `Devices` category, I found the `Typing` entry missing.

I then went to `Connected devices` to try to `Add devices`, but after I clicked the button, the system kept searching for devices and then just stalled without any response.

What else should I do now? I just want to activate the spell check without installing any third party software. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just to test. Does changing the language to English (US) [as in this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/typing-option-under-devices-is-missing/3b2fd3ca-23b4-4b60-b152-5361a373a0df?page=2) help?

Comment: @w32sh I'm sorry but I can't change it to English, because my system is a Chinese version and perhaps due to some default settings the display language can only be Chinese.

Comment: @w32sh ok, after I've changed the default language to Eng US, the `Typing` menu finally appeared. But still, the spell check doesn't work at all even if activated. I suppose there's something wrong with the spell check dictionary file.